# Get Bounding Box of clipped element

Tags: svg

I have an SVG which has such some elements which look like so:

```
<svg>
   <defs>
     <symbol id="image">
       <image
         xlink:href="../png/SpongeBob.jpg"
         y="35.02803"
         x="-81.995514"
         height="203.2"
         width="361.24442" />
     </symbol>
     <clipPath id="clipPath4981" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
       <rect
         y="35.02803"
         x="-81.995514"
         height="67.732658"
         width="120.41361" />
     </clipPath>
   </defs>
  <use
   clip-path="url(#clipPath4981)"
   y="0"
   x="0"
   xlink:href="#image" />
</svg>
```

As the docs say for `getBBox()`:

> Returns the tight bounding box in current user space (i.e., after application of the ‘transform’ attribute, if any) on the geometry of all contained graphics elements, **exclusive of stroking, clipping** […]

But I need to get the bounding box the the element, such that the clipping is taken in account.

Right now, the bounding box I get looks like that:

[image]

How can I compute such a Bounding Box?

Comment: With mathematics. You want the intersection of two rectangles.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but could you please elaborate a bit on this? Which Rectangles, gained from where?

Comment: The ones in your markup, the image and the clipPath.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99565/simplest-way-to-calculate-the-intersect-area-of-two-rectangles

Comment: So the intersection of `use.getBBox()` and `symbol.getBBox()` will do the trick?

Comment: Well Firefox (and probably other UAs too) does not support symbol.getBBox() as that's not a directly rendered element.

Comment: What about transformations? Do I need to apply the same transformation to the clipPath, gained from the `<defs>` as the one applied to the `<use>`??

Comment: You'll need to use the the `x` `y` `width`and `height` coordinates of the `<image>` and the `<rect>` to calculate your rectangle intersection.  The clip is applied to the original object before it is transformed.